# PHP: SQL connection in File 1, SQL functions in File 2 not working

Tags: php

I have File 1 called `init.php` which holds the SQL details and SQL connection:

```
<?php
$sql = array(
    'user'     => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'server'   => '192.168.100.1', 
    'db'       => 'XE'
);

$conn = oci_connect($sql['user'], $sql['password'], $sql['server'].'/'.$sql['db']);

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error( htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR );
}


include("functions.php");
?>
```

I have File 2 called `functions.php` which holds SQL functions:

```
<?php
function is_accessible($a, $b) {
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select c1 from t1 where o1 = $a");

    oci_execute($stid);

    $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM);

    if ($row['0'] == $b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function ...
?>
```

The `functions.php` file does not seem to want to use the connection I have in `init.php`, why is this?

If I put the SQL connection directly in the `is_accessible` function then it works.

Comment: Try passing the connection variable to the function; it's most likely a scope issue.

Comment: *"If I put the SQL connection directly in the `is_accessible` function then it works."* - Then that's what you must do, as I stated above. It's a scope issue. Try and not use global though; many many many think it's a bad idea, *just saying*.

Comment: But I don't want a massive connection block in 100+ functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **global**  to define your connection inside your function

```
function is_accessible($a, $b) {
    global $conn;
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select c1 from t1 where o1 = $a");

    oci_execute($stid);

    $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM);

    if ($row['0'] == $b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and dont forget to run your function